# How to use ScenarioStepContext in hook?

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I am using SpecFlow with NUnit3 and am trying to access the step context within a hook.

I am running the tests in parallel so not using any static instance contexts, but using the parameter resolving feature of SpecFlow.

With a hook like below, the ScenarioContext instance resolves fine, but the ScenarioStepContext causes the binding to throw error:

> Primitive types or structs cannot be resolved: TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.StepDefinitionType (resolution path: TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioStepContext->TechTalk.SpecFlow.StepInfo)'

```
[AfterStep]
public void LogStepResult(ScenarioStepContext scenarioStepContext,
    ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it buried in some documentation...

Instead of trying to resolve the `ScenarioStepContext`, you can use the `ScenarioStepContext` that comes with the resolved `ScenarioContext` in the StepContext property:

```
[AfterStep]
public void LogStepResult(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
{
    var stepContext = scenarioContext.StepContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using parallel execution in your tests, then you can call ScenarioContext directly. Here is an [example](http://specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/). If you are running tests in parallel, then you can use previous answer.