# How can I use the name of a step in my error logs? NUnit, Specflow, C#

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, specflow, scenarios

I am automating tests as end-to-end scenarios, therefore I have multiple Thens, e.g.

```
Scenario: My scenario
Given a
When b
Then check something 1
When c
Then check something 2
When d
And e
Then check something 3
```

I am aware that you can access the test's name TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name which you can insert into an error log, but I can't seem to find a way to get the step name.

When the scenario fails, I want to know which Then statement it failed on, e.g...

```
string errorLog += "Scenario \"" + TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name + "\" failed on test step: \"" + testStepName + "\"."
```

...should produce something like this:

```
Scenario "My scenario" failed on test step: "Then check something 2".
```

Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: I thought the standard output when running a test (basically calls to `Console.WriteLine(...)` are included in the test results. It should show you line-by-line which steps succeeded and which failed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can view the test results in the Visual Studio test explorer. Viewing the details of a test should show every step in the scenario and whether or not that step passed or failed.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I should've mentioned that I'm saving the details to a text file error log on my PC.

Comment: When running tests from the command line (if that is what you are doing) you can set the output to write to a file. I really think you could be utilizing your tools to do this instead of writing code to do this.

Comment: I'm running them in Visual Studio. This is the only approach that came to mind, I was unaware of other approaches.

Comment: You can right-click on the failed test and view the details of the test. It should show you line by line what steps passed and failed.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't help me write the same information to a file automatically. I know I can physically look at the error in VS, my question was how I output the step name to a text file. But I didn't make it clear that I was outputting it to a text file. Apologies.

Comment: I think what I'm saying is you don't need to write things to a file. Running tests from the command line gives you a file with the information you are looking for. Running the tests from visual studio still gives you the information, you just need to view the details of that test.

Comment: What I'm doing appears unnecessary. That's because I haven't been very clear at all! I'm saving screenshots when there's an AssertionException in a folder, so thought it'd be handy to also record the exception message in a text file in the same folder. As my test suite grows in size, I'd rather not wade through numerous tests to find errors, then go to the folder and find which screenshot relates to which error. Both files are named the same, all I have to do is kick off a run and monitor the folder - I only get to see what I care about, easily relating error to screenshot by file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `ScenarioStepContext` [class](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/ScenarioStepContext.cs) and `StepInfo.Text` property. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/425) to add functionality to expose the current step type and text

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski's answer lead me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838738/how-to-use-scenariostepcontext-in-hook which lead me to the solution:
  
  [AfterStep]
        public void GetStepName(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            stepName = scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType + " " + scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text;
        }

Comment: I can't edit the above comment, but you should use BeforeStep instead because if a step causes an AssertionException, the test bombs out before getting that step's name (it'll keep the previous one captured).